# PdfStamper not working in IE, or Adobe, but works in Chrome and FF

Tags: java, pdf, itext, flying-saucer

So Weird,  I am generating a PDF using FlyingSaucer, then adding a footer to the PDF. The footer works in Chrome and FF, but not IE.  But if I download the PDF, even from Chrome, where the text is there, open it locally with Adobe, it is not... I dont get it.

Code:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = originalPDF.getOutputStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream newos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(os.toByteArray());
    PdfStamper stamper  = new PdfStamper(reader, newos);

    for(int i=1; i<= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++){
        Rectangle pageSize = reader.getPageSize(i);
        PdfContentByte content = stamper.getUnderContent(i);
        BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, "utf8", false);
        content.setFontAndSize(baseFont, 15);
        content.setRGBColorFill(0, 0, 0);
        content.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, "Page "+i, 3, 5, 0);
        content.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, " - Printed: "+DateUtil.date2str_MM_dd_yyyy(new Date()), pageSize.getWidth()-3, 5, 0);
    }

    stamper.close();

    request.getSession().setAttribute("file", newos.toByteArray());
```

Any Ideas?

@mkl
EDIT:
I cannot post the PDF, sensitive information and all that BUT, if I change the code to:

```
      PdfContentByte content = stamper.getUnderContent(i);
        String msg = "Page "+i+" - Printed: "+DateUtil.datetime2str_MM_dd_yyyy_h_mm_a(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(content, PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(msg), center, 5, 0);
```

It works on all browsers and Adobe.  So clearly my font and/or encoding is wrong. Any suggestions for proper encoding?

Comment: Please provide a sample result pdf. That been said, utf8 is a weird encoding for Helvetica; underContent might be hidden; xfa forms in PDFs might make things interesting.

Comment: Concerning your edit: the encoding utf8 is not applicable here. Helvetica is one of the standard 14 fonts every viewer knows but only with a WinAnsiEncoding style character set.